# Oracle search by string variable

Tags: oracle, variables

Question is about searching query by string variable.

```
declare
phone varchar(15):='+77071414714';
cnt number:=0;
begin
   SELECT COUNT(*) into cnt   FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE (TELNUMBER=phone OR TELNUMBER LIKE phone);
   dbms_output.put_line(cnt);
end;
```

this code prints 0. while

```
declare
    cnt number:=0;
begin
   SELECT COUNT(*) into cnt   FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE TELNUMBER='+77071414714';
   dbms_output.put_line(cnt);
end;
```

prints 5.
how can i make first code to print 5?

Comment: can you check the data type of column TELNUMBER in the CUSTOMERS table?  Also - aside from your question - note that TELNUMBER LIKE phone will do you no good; you probably want something like TELNUMBER LIKE '%' || phone || '%' or perhaps even more complicated, depending on the possible formats of the TELNUMBER column in your table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
declare phone varchar(30) DEFAULT '+77071414714';
declare cnt number:=0;
begin
   SELECT COUNT(*) into cnt   FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE TELNUMBER=phone; 
   dbms_output.put_line(cnt);
end;
```

Comment: The problem is that i pass the phone variable as parameter to function. so at the time of execution of the code, the "phone" variable is unknown.

Comment: which function are you talking about ??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. The problem was in data type of column TELNUMBER, it was CHAR(15). By changing it to VARCHAR(15), it is solved. Thanks to  mathguy.